# Symfony 6 bunde uninstall twig error "The "xxx" directory does not exist (xxx)"

Tags: symfony, composer-php, symfony6, symfony-process

I am trying to install/uninstall package using Symfony `Process` and `composer`

```php
$commands = [];
if ('1' == $installed) {
   $commands[] = ['php', '/usr/local/bin/composer', 'remove', $extensionName];
}

if ('0' == $installed) {
   $commands[] = ['php', '/usr/local/bin/composer', 'require', $extensionName];
}

foreach ($commands as $command) {
   $process = new Process($command);
   $process->setWorkingDirectory($kernel->getProjectDir());
   $process->setEnv([
       'COMPOSER_HOME' => $kernel->getProjectDir(),
   ]);
   $process->run();

   if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
       throw new \RuntimeException($process->getErrorOutput());
   }
}
```

**The install command works fine using Symfony process but on uninstall it throws erro:** `The "/var/www/vendor/xxx/paypal-bundle/templates" directory does not exist ("/var/www/vendor/xxx/paypal-bundle/templates").`

Here is the bundle definition:

```php
class PaypalBundle extends AbstractBundle
{
    public function prependExtension(ContainerConfigurator $container, ContainerBuilder $builder): void
    {
        $container->extension('twig', [
            'paths' => [
                '%kernel.project_dir%/vendor/xxx/paypal-bundle/templates' => 'PaypalBundle',
            ],
        ]);
        ...
    }
}
```

Running composer install/uninstall command manuallly works fine, But running via symfony process component doesn't work on uninstall.

Comment: What does "on uninstall" mean? Maybe the folder that you've referenced does not exist? How is this problem related to Composer  or Symfony's Process component?

Comment: I mean when I do `composer require <package-name>` using Symfony Process to install the package its works fine. But When I do `composer remove <package-name>` using Symfony Process it throws me that error.

Comment: Would it throw the same error when you use `composer remove` directly (without invoking Symfony Process)? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Like: if the folder does not exist, what's the expected behaviour?

Comment: Yes, the `composer remove` command works fine if I run it manually without the Symfony Process.

I have also tried adding a remove vendor and var folder command then running composer remove with symfony process but I think that didn't work either. Do I need to run cache:clear for twig ?

Comment: How should Twig itself be involved here? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: Because I am passing twig dir path in `prependExtension` funciton whihc could be issue... I have tried to run `rm -rf vendor` and `rm -rf var` before composer command, but it doesn't work

Comment: You haven't checked anywhere whether the folder you try to use even exists. Why not add that in `prependExtension`, as proposed in my very first comment?

Comment: I see. Let me workaround this and add if condtion before adding path to extension.